# How to scan barcode(generated using ZBar SDK) using iPhone simulator?

Tags: ios-simulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [zbar sdk not working on iphone simulator by using camera simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583800/zbar-sdk-not-working-on-iphone-simulator-by-using-camera-simulator)

I want to test my barcode scanner using iPhone Camera.

I'm using ZBar SDK for my barcode scanning.

I have a scan button for this.When I click on Scan button,its showing me the message,"**Camera simulation, tap and hold with two finger to select image**".When I'm doing this,its showing "No photo" in another view.

**Could any one plaese tell me how can I select an barcode image and scan it using simulater?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any images in the simulator to test? If not, images can be added to the simulators photo library two ways.

1. Drag and drop an image from Finder into the simulator. It will open in Safari and you can press and hold the image and an action sheet will pop up asking you to save.
2. Go to Safari directly on the simulator, navigate to the image you want, and save it the same way as in step 1.

Comment: Thanks.Its saving the image and when i'm doing "tap and hold"; its just opening the saved image.How do I scan and read the barcode value?